# Transfer 401k without fees

Tags: united-states, 401k

I had a 401k plan with my company that switched financial firms. The new firm said they had to close it, wait for a check to come from Nationwide and then reopen it up with them. Could this have been done without fees? My company then set up a simple IRA. I think it could have been transferred with no fees. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The fees depend on the previous and the new provider, each of them have their rules and can take fees as they want, if they have it in their policies. As an employee of the company, you have no choice in the provider, so you are bound to the one your company chose.

However, depending on circumstances, you can move your *existing* 401 k savings (Roth or non-Roth) into an IRA with any outside provider/custodian you chose, and they typically offer this *without* any fee, including having the account long term (in the contrary, the kiss your feet, and pay often even the fee from the provider you are coming from, if any; they are of course interested in getting your business).

With the situation you describe, it might be possible to move the *existing* money outside, instead of the new provider your company picked. For future savings through your company, you are again bound to the provider they pick.